# How to decrease mybatis-spring xml files scan time?

Tags: java, spring, performance, tomcat, mybatis

We have a web application contains about more than 400 SQLMap XML files, and it takes about 80 seconds to start up the application. According to profiling and log result, most of cost is scanning XML files in the jars.

Is any way to decrease scan time of XML files?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an option for you, you can disable scanning and tell MyBatis where to find the files, instead of letting it looking for them. This means adding XML configuration for [mappers](http://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#mappers).

I see you have tagged the question "spring", so see if these two links apply to your setup: [Registering a mapper](http://mybatis.org/spring/mappers.html#register) and [SqlSessionFactoryBean](http://mybatis.org/spring/factorybean.html).